# Swift_Mailer + symfony UTF-8

Tags: php, symfony1, character-encoding, swiftmailer

I have an issue with Swift_Mailer in Symfony. I am sending e-mail messages in French which contain a lot of "à é è" characters. At first when i tried sending these characters came out fine in my email-client, but in my colleague's email-client they didn't.

So I put the text for the mail through a utf8_encode function and tried again. Now it is vica-versa. It shows fine in my email-client, but screwed up in my colleague's.

What is the best way to solve these e-mail UTF-8 issues with Swift_Mailer in Symfony?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$message->toString();` to see if your e-mail is well formatted, meaning everything is UTF-8 or uses the proper European ISO charset `iso-8859-15`. You can use `setCharset` to tell it what you're actually using.

> The character set of the message (and it’s MIME parts) is set with the
>   setCharset() method. You can also change the global default of UTF-8
>   by working with the Swift_Preferences class.
>
> Swift Mailer will default to the UTF-8 character set unless otherwise
>   overridden. UTF-8 will work in most instances since it includes all of
>   the standard US keyboard characters in addition to most international
>   characters.
>
> It is absolutely vital however that you know what character set your
>   message (or it’s MIME parts) are written in otherwise your message may
>   be received completely garbled.

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-the-character-set